# Problems with memory upgrade on ProLiant DL380 Gen10

Tags: memory, hpe

I have a server ProLiant DL380 Gen10 Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz with 2 memory bank of 32 GB for each one so 64GB of RAM in total. One of them is produced by Samsung and the other one by SK hynix.

I need to upgrade the memory to 128GB so I bought a new only bank of memory of 64GB (produced by Samsung) and I installed physically on the server but the memory has not been recognized from the host and it shows that are only 64GB of available memory.

I will attach here the tags of each memory component if it can be helpful:

SK hynix 32GB: HMA84GR7AFR4N
Samsung 32GB: M393A4K40CB2
Samsung 64GB: M393A8G40MB2

How can I identify and troubleshoot the problem?

Thank you so much in advance for any helps.

Comment: Did you populate RAM on slots 8, 10 and 12?

Comment: @RomeoNinov First tried this configuration: [link](https://ibb.co/RPKGb5R)
Then tried this configuration: [link](https://ibb.co/mJV366h)

Comment: Both configurations you set are supported. My doubts are the server expect the same size RDIMMs. Can't find document confirming this (or opposite)

Comment: @RomeoNinov where you checked if my configurations are supported? I can not find nothing about it. How can I be sure of that (same size RDIMMs)? Thank you so much for your replies!

Comment: I did not found any pro/cons about same size. About population checked here: https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/a00017079enw , https://www.itcreations.com/user-manuals/dl160-10/server-memory-population-rules-for-hpe-gen10-servers-with-intel-xeon-scalable-processors-white-paper.pdf?nr